# Нужен модуль для отображения фото в окне терминала python

Tags: python

Делаю простую игру про угадывание флагов, основная часть уже написана, но нужен модуль для отображения фото, обычное открытие фото не то, кроме этого есть вариант открывать в окне pygame/tkinter, но хотелось бы отображать в окне самой игры. Находил один подходящий модуль - https://habr.com/ru/post/102315/ , установил, но сайт с документацией уже все, остальных сайтов с этим модулем = 0

Comment: Вот тут много решений, выбирайте https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413540/showing-an-image-from-console-in-python

Answer (score 0):

Если надо прям в теpминале с невысоким качеством, то
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/display-images-on-terminal-using-python/

```
    import climage
  
    output = climage.convert('.png')
  
    print(output)
```